# Append a number to duplicate values in data table c#

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I have a datatable that might contain following data in one of the columns

```
ID    Name      Other Cols
--------------------------
1     Apple
2     Apple
3     Apple
4     Orange
5     Orange
6     Mango
7     Banana
```

What I would like to do is to append a number after each duplicate value such that i get following output.

```
ID    Name     Other Cols
-------------------------
1     Apple
2     Apple1
3     Apple2
4     Orange
5     Orange1
6     Mango
7     Banana
```

What the efficient way of doing this? My table can contain close to 5 million records and performance is a concern.

PS: I have to ultimately convert this data into list/dictionary of objects.

**UPDATE 1 - MY LINQ/List in simplified form**

```
 Dim items = (From p In dataSet.Tables("personal").AsEnumerable().Skip(totalFetched).Take(1000).ToList()
                     Join m In dataSet.Tables("members").AsEnumerable().Skip(totalFetched).Take(1000).ToList() On p("members_Id") Equals m("members_Id")
                     Join a In dataSet.Tables("agreement").AsEnumerable().Skip(totalFetched).Take(1000).ToList() On p("members_Id") Equals a("members_Id")
                     Select New ClubInformation() With {
                        .MemberId = clubNumber & a.Field(Of String)("agreementNumber"),
                        .FirstName = p.Field(Of String)("firstName"), 
                        .LastName = p.Field(Of String)("lastName")
                    }).ToList()
```

I will have duplicates here and would like to append some number afterwards

```
.MemberId = clubNumber & a.Field(Of String)("agreementNumber")
```

Comment: If you can get them into a List<string> then linq is your best bet

Comment: Is your data table currently in memory or in sql?

Comment: The data is in-memory and is fetched via thrid party API in json format.

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre I already have it in list, but then appending would require manipulating each item within the list using some logic which i think will really slow it down.....i will update my question to show what i have in the linq

Comment: Is this c# or VB.net.  The tag says c#.  If you need a dictionary I recommend Dictionary<key,List<DataRow>>.  You don't need a seperate list.  The dictionary doesn't copy the DataTable instead it adds links between the key and the existing rows of the DataTable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data is already in a `List<string>` then this can be done by taking each value and looping through to replace the values like so

```
int num = 0;
foreach (var fruit in fruits.Where(item => item == "Orange")) //Orange can be a variable instead when looping through unknown items
{
    num++
    fruit = num > 1 ? fruit + num.ToString() : fruit;
}
```

If you don't know what values will be in the List before it is made, you can also do this

```
var duplicateFruit = fruits.GroupBy(fruit => fruit).SelectMany(grp => grp.Skip(1).Take(1));
foreach(var val in duplicateFruit)
{
    int num = 0;
    foreach (var fruit in fruits.Where(item => item == val)) 
    {
        num++
        fruit = num > 1 ? fruit + num.ToString() : fruit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alfie. This worked. Now I only have to watch out for performance slowdowns....but this really helped!!!

Comment: It ran fast enough? If so I am glad I helped!

Comment: The client said he doesn't care about performance :) So i guess it worked

Answer (score 1):

Use linq with something like this. Not sure how this will work performance wise with a few million in the list but you get the idea:

```
var myList = new List<MyClass>() { new MyClass { Id = 1, Name = "Apple" }, 
         new MyClass { Id = 2, Name = "Apple" }, new MyClass { Id = 3, Name = "Orange" } };

var newList = myList.Select((x, y) => new MyClass
{
    Id = x.Id,
    Name = x.Name + " " + 
   (myList.GetRange(0, y).Count(z => z.Name == x.Name) == 0 ? string.Empty : 
                             myList.GetRange(0, y).Count(z => z.Name == x.Name).ToString())
});
```

.Net Fiddle

https://dotnetfiddle.net/kKCda1

Comment: I get the gist though your dotnetfiddle example throws execution time limit was reached error. I have similar idea to do this if nothing else works, the concern still remains that performance might be impacted while looping through items. I will run some test and see how it looks.

Comment: The .net fiddle runs fine for me. Did you just press run ? It runs automatically the result is in the bottom window.

Comment: Clever solution. I did some light performance testing. As you might expect, the performance goes down exponentially as the number of items in the list goes up. 5000 items was comfortably under 1/2 second, 20000 items clocked in around 6 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Using Linq you can do it easily:-

```
var fruits= new List<Fruit>() { new Fruit { Id = 1, Name = "Apple" }, 
     new Fruit { Id = 2, Name = "Apple" }, new Fruit { Id = 3, Name = "Orange" } };
var duplicates = fruits.GroupBy(x => x.Name)
            .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
            .Select(y => y)
            .ToList();
        foreach (var fruit in duplicates)
        {
            var index = 0;
            fruit.ToList().ForEach(l => l.Name = $"{l.Name}{index++ > 1 ? (index-1).ToString() : string.Empty}");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you already have accepted a solution, but this is very readable to me.

```
fruits
.GroupBy(p => p.Name)
.SelectMany(g =>
{
   g.Select((tmp, index) =>
   {
       tmp.Name = index == 0 ? tmp.Name : $"{tmp.Name}{index}";
       return tmp;
   }).ToList();
   return g;
}).ToList();
```